# Copy/Paste of quoted text crashing Mathematica 10?

Tags: bugs, crash

(Mathematica 10.01 under Windows 7)

Create two text cells and in each of them place the following text:

```
<table align="left" style="margin-left:50px; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 0.9em;">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="font-style: italic;"><td>Datum</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Schipper</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Plaats</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Van - Naar</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11-5-1761</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam - Østersøen</td></tr>
    <tr><td>26-6-1761</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reinders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1-9-1761</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Riga</td></tr>
    <tr><td>19-10-1761</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pietter Reinders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>26-6-1762</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reinders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Hamborg</td></tr>
    <tr><td>15-5-1763</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reinderts</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Warden</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam - Østersøen</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10-8-1763</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Narwa - Amsterdam</td></tr>
    <tr><td>23-5-1764</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Simon Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Warder</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Liebau</td></tr>
    <tr><td>25-7-1764</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynderts</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Narwa - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>21-9-1764</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reinders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Narwa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>18-11-1764</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Narva - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>17-5-1765</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Narwa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6-9-1765</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Narva</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4-12-1765</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieters Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Narva - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>24-5-1767</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Østersøen</td></tr>
    <tr><td>21-7-1767</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Wisby - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>24-5-1768</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Riga</td></tr>
    <tr><td>24-7-1768</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11-9-1768</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Riga</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4-11-1768</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reinders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>27-4-1769</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Riga</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10-6-1769</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5-9-1769</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam - Østersøen</td></tr>
    <tr><td>30-10-1769</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Amsterdam</td></tr>
    <tr><td>15-5-1770</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Riga</td></tr>
    <tr><td>14-7-1770</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reinders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Ostende</td></tr>
    <tr><td>27-8-1770</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reynders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Ostende - Riga</td></tr>
    <tr><td>25-10-1770</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Pieter Reinders</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Amsterdam</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Riga - Ostende</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Also create an input cell with an empty string.

Copy one of the text cells as plain text and insert it in the empty string. Mathematica asks if escapes must be added. Answer YES and it works. Then select both text cells, copy as plain text and insert in the empty string. Again, Mathematica asks if escapes must be added. Answer YES and, at least on my system, Mathematica stops working.

When we copy one cell as plain text, it can be inserted a number of times in a string without causing Mathematica to crash. So my feeling is that copy as plain text cannot correctly copy a long text.

Is this crash due to some setting of my system, or is it a bug?

Comment: It looks like your text did not copy correctly.  Or do you really intend for us top copy the html stuff?  Perhaps you could put it in a code block for clarity.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is not important that the text that has to be placed in the two text cells is correct html code. It just has to be text with quotation marks. I tested this stack exchange question exactly as I described (and right now once again): I copied and pasted the html stuff from this page in two Mathematica text cells. Inserting the plain text from one of these cells in an empty string is OK, but Mathematica stops working when I insert the plain text of the two cells. If it does not work in this way on your computer, it must be due to my system somewhere.

Comment: I can reproduce the crash on V10.0.1, Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: On Linux all I needed to do was cut and paste into a fresh notebook. Result: no notebook. Reported as a crash bug.

Comment: @Daniel Tagged accordingly.  Do you know in which version this problem was introduced?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No idea when it was introduced.

Comment: Still exists in 10.0.2

Comment: it does not crash on 10.1, but it hangs instead :)